# Reconstruct the ASCII art from a string

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

I have a bunch of ASCII art that I have recovered from a failed hard drive. Unfortunately, all of the newlines were stripped out, and I don't know the resolution of the original artwork. I do know that each one was originally rectangular, but to make matters worse, all the white space at the beginning and end was stripped out too!

I *do* at least know what one small piece of each one looks like. Can you help me recover the artwork based on the input stream of bytes and the piece of ASCII art I remember?

### Example

I remember this one:

```
__(((55^$$%^/\__%%//\/_666332@12
```

Had this diamond in it:

```
/\
\/
```

The original artwork in this case was 8 characters wide:

```
__(((55^
$$%^/\__
%%//\/_6
66332@12
```

Then there's this one, which had a bigger diamond in it.

```
/\/\/\/\/\:;/  \00F\/\/\  /E%epopox\/e
```

The diamond looked like this:

```
 /\
/  \
\  /
 \/
```

The original artwork contained that diamond, but the white space surrounding the diamond was not white space in the original artwork. I’ve only added in the white space to the left to get the indentation right.

More generally, in each row, any space to the left of the first non-white-space character is indentation padding, and any white space to the right necessarily represents actual white space.

Note that this is also one of those pieces that has had its white space trimmed off. Here's the original, 11 characters wide, with white space restored:

```
   /\/\/\/\
/\:;/  \00F
\/\/\  /E%e
popox\/e
```

Remember, the amount of white space removed is unknown. That means I can’t even figure out the possibilities for line length by finding the divisors of the input’s character count.

### Input

A string of characters (the artwork, sans newlines, trimmed of white space at the beginning and end), and a two-dimensional string of characters (the piece to look for)

Essentially, the string of characters can be generated from the original artwork thus: `artwork.Replace("\n", "").Trim(" ")`

### Output

The original artwork with newlines inserted where necessary, and with trimmed white space re-added to the beginning of the first line and the end of the last line. If there is more than one possible solution, you may return one arbitrarily (or all of them if you really want to).

### Test Cases

```
Input:
__(((55^$$%^/\__%%//\/_666332@12
/\
\/

Output:
__(((55^
$$%^/\__
%%//\/_6
66332@12

-----------
Input:
 _-/\-_-_vv:;/  \00F\\||\  /E%epopox\/e0
 /\
/  \
\  /
 \/

Output:
   _-/\-_-_
vv:;/  \00F
\\||\  /E%e
popox\/e0  


--------
Input:
__               (  )               ||                ||            ___|""|__.._     /____________\    \____________/~~~.
(  )
 ||
 ||
 ""

Output:
     __           
    (  )          
     ||           
     ||           
 ___|""|__.._     
/____________\    
\____________/~~~.


--------
Input:
..XX...XX.......X..X..X  X.....X..X...X  X.....XX......XX...
 XX 
X  X
X  X
 XX 

Output:
..XX...XX.......
X..X..X  X.....X
..X...X  X.....X
X......XX...
```

Notably, in this last case, the following is *not* valid output:

```
..XX...XX......
.X..X..X  X....
.X..X...X  X...
..XX......XX...
```

Credit to jrei @ [asciiart.eu](https://www.asciiart.eu/computers/joysticks) for the joystick

### Rules

- This is code golf, so shortest answer in bytes wins.
- Default I/O rules apply

Comment: Is it a problem if we return some extra row of white spaces at the begin/end? Can the pattern have a row/column of white spaces at the begin/end?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the output is rectangular (all row have the same length)?

Comment: Is it OK if we assume that _any space_ in the original artwork may have been replaced with another character, or are we supposed to make sure that _only surrounding spaces_ have been replaced?

Comment: there are many solutions, for example for the 2nd case the output could also be `          _`
`-/\-_-_vv:;`
`/  \00F\\||`
`\  /E%epopo`
`x\/e0`

Comment: @user202729 Yes, the output will always be rectangular (although the input does not necessarily contain all of the characters necessary to create such a rectangle, due to missing white space)

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul as noted in the original question, if there is more than one answer, you can output an arbitrary one.

Comment: @Arnauld not sure exactly what you mean... if you are referring to the space around the diamond in the example, only the space around the outside may actually be another character. If there is any space between two non-white-space characters, either horizontally or vertically, it necessarily represents white space.

Comment: @user202729 one could argue that since the amount of white space that has been trimmed out is unknown, you can add in an arbitrary amount of white space before the first row or after the last row. I always store my ASCII art in as compact a form as possible though, so the original did not have any blank rows at the top or bottom, or any blank columns on the left or right.

Comment: [Here is an example](https://tio.run/##fY69CoAwDIT3e4qQUbDuLs6@gGQt6qBIFa2@fv2pYMlgCDkSjvsy2sNu7TosPndz14ciC7Vbdl@CjREx77hLYhNJsib763uUASYRYvBt@CQeUbvDTkNH8@4vWAXFgoJB0aBwQPMXZ6B/h34eaRxdFbIinA) where it does make a difference. If the 1st output really is invalid, then I think you should add such a test case because it makes the challenge significantly harder.

Comment: @Arnauld noted. Your example has been added

Comment: Can I use other variables than spaces for the padding of "small piece", or does it have to be whitespaces? (Only applies if we can input the small piece as a matrix, like Jonah asked)

Comment: @Jonah he answered that before, scroll up a few comments.

Comment: Can you confirm that if the following is the "small piece", all spaces are necessary. `X  X\n XX \n XX \nX  X`

Comment: @Kroppeb I’m fine with any convenient padding, as long as the input is still rectangular.

Comment: Can we use standard input rules and take the part we're searching for as a matrix (rather than a string with newlines separating each one)?

Comment: @Jonah As noted in the original post, yes, default I/O rules apply.

Comment: @Kroppeb I have revised the detection of padding to indicate that the horizontal spacing in that example is still padding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 192 bytes

To be golfed more

```perl
($_,@F)=@F;$l=max map length,@F;map{$_.=" "x($l-y///c);s/(^ +| +$)|\W/$1=~y, ,.,r||"\\$&"/gme}@F;for$i(0..y///c){$"=".{$i}";$i+=$l,$_=" "x($i-"@-").$_,map{printf"%-$i\s
",$_}/.{1,$i}/g if/@F/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVHBasJAEL3vVwzLpiSY3YlKPBgCuTSn9lh6GRykRLsQk6BBFFc/vemm9tD20IE5zHvz3huYrtrX6TCEiuOijPKizFSd79Yn2K07qKtm2797IvPTRbHJJchTqGp9RsS3KDtguIKJg4mKHL2imua3cwyxiffOSSL1IHG7q67eYNPulQ0TY@7Ki5K5NBdlrzJTdpKrOlb87W61LLSMjD9pjO32tuk3MtDK0kFIv3dFc5nGXotbsBssSrwOA3MYhmm6UipYITEHASIhLxaL@XxWTGcCSRAKAayRNGs@HpcZAlCSlETOEQA@BlXXdu2JsEoEeMHIi5ERMGqZ4XeFANEfyDn4F2FmJ6VjNubuhvyjaEToJ4K3282IMUh4p3tLKT7arrdtcxh0kjSDfn6yh365fOnt1/cGvS6RGvREapLpJw)

Comment: Can this be adjusted to make sure it outputs a rectangular image? It’s missing the extra space on the last line.